# How to upload document like PDF , .txt from iPhone programatically in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, document

I need to upload the documents from iPhone like we upload image from Gallery . I need to implement it in Swift 4.

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For upload document you use `UIDocumentPicker`. On this given link you know about UIDocumentPicker

[Implement Document Picker in swift (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37296929/implement-document-picker-in-swift-ios/42370660)