# UIDocumentPickerViewController - 'init(documentTypes:in:)' was deprecated in iOS 14.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

Method is deprecated from iOS 14, so need support for both iOS 14 and later. And iOS 13 and earlier.

Answer (score 18):

Here is the complete code written in **Swift 5** to support earlier version of **iOS 14 and later**

This method is deprecated from iOS 14

```
public init(documentTypes allowedUTIs: [String], in mode: UIDocumentPickerMode)
```

1. Write this code in your button action

   ```
   import UniformTypeIdentifiers

   @IBAction func importItemFromFiles(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

            var documentPicker: UIDocumentPickerViewController!
            if #available(iOS 14, *) {
                // iOS 14 & later
                let supportedTypes: [UTType] = [UTType.image]
                documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: supportedTypes)
            } else {
                // iOS 13 or older code
                let supportedTypes: [String] = [kUTTypeImage as String]
                documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: supportedTypes, in: .import)
            }
            documentPicker.delegate = self
            documentPicker.allowsMultipleSelection = true
            documentPicker.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
            self.present(documentPicker, animated: true)
        }
   ```
2. Implement Delegates

// MARK: - UIDocumentPickerDelegate Methods

```
extension MyViewController: UIDocumentPickerDelegate {
        func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
            
            for url in urls {
                
                // Start accessing a security-scoped resource.
                guard url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() else {
                    // Handle the failure here.
                    return
                }
                
                do {
                    let data = try Data.init(contentsOf: url)
                    // You will have data of the selected file
                }
                catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
                
                // Make sure you release the security-scoped resource when you finish.
                defer { url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource() }
            }
        }
        
        func documentPickerWasCancelled(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
            controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Comment: import UniformTypeIdentifiers in case using UTType.image to made it in scope

Comment: It's much easier to create `UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: supportedTypes, asCopy: true)` which is a fallback to `.import` previously. After that you don't need to worry about calling `startAccessingSecurityScopedResource`, `stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource`

Answer (score -1):

```
   import UniformTypeIdentifiers

   let contentTypes: [UTType] = [
      .init(filenameExtension: "doc")!,
      .init(filenameExtension: "docx")!,
      .pdf,
      .presentation,
      .spreadsheet,
      .plainText,
      .text
   ]

    let documentPicker: UIDocumentPickerViewController

    if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
        documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: contentTypes, asCopy: true)
    } else {
        documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: contentTypes.map({$0.identifier}), in: .import)
    }
```