# How to enable enable both the iCloud and the Key-Sharing capabilities in Xcode 11?

Tags: swift, xcode

I want to reproduce the answer of this question : [Implement Document Picker in swift (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37296929/implement-document-picker-in-swift-ios)

But I can't From my project's capabilities, enable both the iCloud and the Key-Sharing.
Xcode 11 seems to have change the interface.[Here is the interface I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhgBK.jpg)

Comment: They are on this list. Try type to search or just scroll down.

Comment: thanks you very much