# Does using UIDocumentPickerViewController need iCloud capability to be enabled?

Tags: ios, swift, document, icloud, cloudkit

I have an application with chat feature.

In this, the user is able to attach a document using the app for which I am using UIDocumentPickerViewController. But I read that it requires iCloud capability to be enabled along with an iCloud Container.

The app does not create any document on iCloud, but just provides an option to attach and existing document along with a chat message.

I want to know whether enabling iCloud is really needed for this use case. Also, the app does not require the document to be on iCloud, it is fine even if the app is able to access only local documents.

I did read here: [Implement Document Picker in swift (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37296929/implement-document-picker-in-swift-ios/65917880) that iOS 14 does not require any capabilities but could not find any official document to support this claim.

Comment: You most likely don't need capabilities. Try testing it out and see if it works

Comment: @aheze It is working fine on debug and adhoc builds, but not sure if Apple will reject the app when submitted to App Store. Also, I have not been able to find any official documentation which states that the iCloud capability is not required.

Comment: But have you found any documentation that says iCloud capability is **required**? If not then you should be fine.

Comment: Btw I have an [open-source app](https://github.com/aheze/ProgressGif) that's live on the App Store with `UIDocumentPickerViewController` and no iCloud capability added. It got rejected once, but because of something else (I was using the Photos app logo, which infringed copyright...)

Comment: I could find this documentation which I dont think is updated since 2015: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentPickerProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014451

Comment: Yeah that's definitely out of date.

Comment: @aheze I checked your app, but it seems to only support videos. I hope things are not different for files other than images and videos.

Comment: @aheze Can you put this as an answer?

Comment: Sure! So you didn't need to add any capabilities right?

Comment: Yes, my app got approved without iCloud capabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do **not** need iCloud capability to be enabled for `UIDocumentPickerViewController`. It doesn't require *any* capabilities actually.