# How to access Cloud drives to import files to my app in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, dropbox, icloud

I want to get documents from Cloud services like iCloud , google drive and dropbox on a button click (like in WhatsApp screenshot below), does anyone know how to do it in swift ? Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/50397424/2171764

Answer (score 15):

From your project's capabilities. First enable both the iCloud services and the Key-Sharing, import MobileCoreServices in your class and finally extended the following three classes inside your UIViewController :

```
UIDocumentMenuDelegate,UIDocumentPickerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate
```

Implement the following functions :

```
 public func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL) {
              let myURL = url as URL
              print("import result : /(myURL)")
    }


public func documentMenu(_ documentMenu:UIDocumentMenuViewController, didPickDocumentPicker documentPicker: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
        documentPicker.delegate = self
        present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


func documentPickerWasCancelled(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
            print("view was cancelled")
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

How to call all of this? Add the following bit of code to your click function..

```
func clickFunction(){

let importMenu = UIDocumentMenuViewController(documentTypes: [String(kUTTypePDF)], in: .import)
            importMenu.delegate = self
            importMenu.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet       
            self.present(importMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Click your button. The following menu will pop up ..

[image: MenuPicker]

In the case of DropBox. Upon clicking on any item. You will be redirected back to your app and the URL will be logged in your terminal.

[image]

Manipulate the documentTypes to your need. In my app, Users permitted to Pdf only. So, suit yourself.

`kUTTypePDF`

Also if you feel like customizing your own menu bar. Add the following code and customize your own function inside the handler

```
        importMenu.addOption(withTitle: "Create New Document", image: nil, order: .first, handler: { print("New Doc Requested") })
```

[image]

Enjoy it.

Comment: cannot set to "public.audio"
showing this error  " showing this error "Passed in type public.pdf doesn't conform to either public.content or public.item. If you are exporting a new type, please ensure that it conforms to an appropriate parent type."

Comment: While initialising the UIDocumentMenuViewController, my app is getting crashed @Alexander

Comment: @Mansuu.... `UIDocumentMenuViewController` is not the class to be implement buddy, again the classes you need are `1.UIDocumentMenuDelegate`, `2.UIDocumentPickerDelegate` and `3.UINavigationControllerDelegate` just tested the chunks of code above and everything is working smoothly, remember to enable your Key-Sharing as well

Comment: I did the same as You suggested above. Enabled key sharing as well, but app crashes. @Alexander

Comment: @Mansuu.... what does the debugger say ? also did you import MobileCoreServices ?

Comment: I ve done everything as you mentioned and I got the URL but now how to  upload it to the server I do not know ) does anyone have any sample project?

Comment: this is what i was searching for https://stackoverflow.com/a/39752152/6515342   and firebase I think has nothing to do with it

Answer (score 2):

First enable iCloud documents Capabilitie, see Apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentPickerProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014451)

The you have to use `UIDocumentMenuViewController`

```
let importMenu = UIDocumentMenuViewController(documentTypes: doctypes, inMode: .Import)
importMenu.delegate = self
importMenu.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = self.addButon;
self.presentViewController(importMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: What do I do with the temporary url that I initially get from the documentpicker? I noticed that my pdfView displays that temporary url easily, but it only remains valid for a few minutes at most.  In other words, when should I take the .lastcomponent from that temporary url and make it permanent by adding it to the Document path? I hope these questions make sense.