# Handling try and throws in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Before Swift 3 I was using:

```
guard let data = Data(contentsOf: url) else {
                print("There was an error!)
                return
            }
```

However I now have to use `do`, `try` and `catch`. I'm not familiar with this syntax. How would I replicate this behaviour?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

The difference here is that `Data(contentsOf: url)` does not return an Optional anymore, it throws.

So you can use it in Do-Catch but without `guard`:

```
do {
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
    // do something with data
    // if the call fails, the catch block is executed
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Note that you could still use `guard` with `try?` instead of `try` but then the possible error message is ignored. In this case, you don't need a Do-Catch block:

```
guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
    print("There was an error!")
    // return or break
}
// do something with data
```

Comment: Thanks for this! The second example is exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: @Moritz Is there a way to add the error message to the else clause? 

Comment: @GitSync Not with `try?`, no. You need Do-Try-Catch to get the error message.

Comment: @Moritz Thanks for the simple answer